# Stuck at GRUB menu

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, live-cd, format

I feel really dumb saying this...

Thanks to the help I received on this forum, I finally fixed my Wine/Pipelight issue and could finally upgrade from 'Trusty' to 'Utopic'. To clean up extra files, someone recommended I try GTKOrphan tool to remove orphaned files.

Well... I ran the thing. This thing should get its priorities straight as far as what is 'optional' or not. Because now, I'm stuck at the GRUB command line. My RescueCD won't boot, and I have no idea how to make it recognize the LiveCD I've copied to my flash drive.

I have no idea of the extent of the damage GTKOrphan did to my computer. I have no idea which libraries it removed or retained.

I just need a step-by-step on how to reformat the computer and reinstall with LiveCD from a flash drive in the GRUB command line. You know, the one that says...

`GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-15`

`Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere TAB lists possible device or file completions.`

Help me, Obi-wan Kenobi... you're my only hope!

Comment: Please... I'm begging you. I've tried everything I know. If there's ANYONE out there who knows anything about how to fix my computer, I'm begging you to help. This is an SOS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to reinstall from the GRUB command! Reboot your computer, the BIOS should flash up a bit of text telling you how to change the boot order - it could be <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> or something else! You need to either just enter BIOS & change it or use the quick option from the boot-up; if it gets to grub, you let it go too far..

Having got the 'device to boot' list, pick your flash drive & you're hopefully cooking..

If you have to do it in BIOS, set Flash before Hard-drive & it will boot from flash (if present) or HDD if not - but be aware, it will continue to do so, so best change it back when you're done.